# VSCode に拡張機能をインストール後、settings.json で構文エラー: Expected comma

Tags: json, vscode

VSCodeに拡張機能「PasteImage」を入れました。
コピーした画像の保存先を指定したいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

保存したい場所：HTMLファイルがある場所にimageフォルダを作り、そこに保存したい

PasteImageではHTMLファイルと同一の場所に画像が保存されますので、setting.json に以下のように記述しました。（上２行のコードは無視してください）

```js
{
    "emmet.variables": {
        "lang": "ja"
    }
    "pasteImage.path": "${currentFileDir}/image"
}
```

ここまで記入しましたが、「コンマが足りない」というエラーメッセージが表示されます。どこに追加すれば良いのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: そのまさに無視しようとしている`}`の後ろに必要なのでは？ [VS Code でEmmet使ったらHTML書くの速くなった～‼](https://qiita.com/tedkuma/items/67876e6be3369b0e730c) スクリーンショットの`5`と`6`を参照。他にもこんな記事が。[htmlをラクして書きたい! Emmetの設定と使い方 with VSCode (html編)](https://pouhon.net/html-emmet/430/), [Visual Studio CodeのEmmetのlang属性をjaに変更する方法](https://webrandum.net/vscode-emmet-lang-ja/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
{
    "emmet.variables": {
        "lang": "ja"
    },  ←ここです！
    "pasteImage.path": "${currentFileDir}/image"
}
```